# Can not understand the result of request JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a function that return an ArrayList< String > ,the list contain elements retrieved from database using JPA ,my problem is that I can't understand the format of the output!

the function is:

```
public ArrayList<String> getMyListEnvironment()
{

  ArrayList<String> env=new ArrayList<String>();
     try{
        EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();

       javax.persistence.Query multipleSelect= em.createQuery("SELECT h.hEnv FROM HPe h WHERE h.hPePK.pePlatform = :w ").setParameter("w", "platf1");
     List s =  new LinkedList();
     s= multipleSelect.getResultList();
     env = new ArrayList(s);

       entr.commit(); 

 return env;
      }
      catch (Exception e )
      {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("error");
      }
      finally {
        em.close();
    } 

  return env;
}
```

The output(Result):

```
[DTOMonito.HEnv[ envUrl=http://10.55.99.5:1055 ], DTOMonito.HEnv[ envUrl=http://10.55.99.99:8090 ]]
```

Comment: Your list look like it contains 2 DTOMonito objects.  Each of them have an envUrl.  What are you expecting?

Comment: @Cygnusx1 ,I am expecting a list like this :   [envUrl=http://10.55.99.5:1055,envUrl=http://10.55.99.99:8090]

Comment: What is the name of your table in the BD? What is the DTOMonito object?  Is it the name of the object mapped to the database table?

Comment: @Cygnusx1 ,DTOMonito  is name of the package that contain java classes ,HEnv is the name of class that map the entity hEnv

Comment: Ha ok...  Because the way you wrote it, it looks like a Class.  In java, the standard is to name packages in lower case and class with Uppercase as the first letter ;-)  So the result seems to be ok!

Answer (score 1):

The query is returning the list of `hEnv` found as fields of the the `HPe` entity (seems like these abbreviations for the entities cause more confusion than good - it's a good idea to use descriptive names for these type of things).

Is `HPe.hEnv` a String? Perhaps your output is confusing because someone is storing a formatted string in this field. Without seeing your code, this is very hard to decipher.

Btw, this method is a bit wasteful for creating [dead stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store). There is absolutely no point in writing something like this:

```
List s =  new LinkedList();
s= multipleSelect.getResultList();
```

You could save a line of code (and a LinkedList allocation) by just writing

```
List s = multipleSelect.getResultList();
```